# The value of useState varies for array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use React hooks to manage a list of  and saving it to localStorage.
Now, all works perfectly fine until the moment when I'm trying to invoke adding outside of the main context of the function (component).

Take a look at the code: https://repl.it/repls/AjarDistortedWeb

When using buttons to add items to list all goes well (There are some additional console.log statements to keep track of what's going on).
Everything breaks when clicking outside of the red box to add an item.

Example flow in text
(input value) 1 -> (Click) Add -> (List contains) 1
(input value) 2 -> (Click) Add -> (List contains) 1, 2
(input value) 2 -> (Click) Delete -> (List contains) 1
(input value) 2 -> (Click) Clean -> (List contains) *empty*
*All good until this moment*

Now try clicking outside the red box with input 'a' let's say. Some previous values somehow gets in the list.

Actually, it seems like clicking buttons and clicking outside keeps track of their own values.

How it's possible and what to do about it?

I tried moving pieces around (to different files, all in one file). Also tried to use 'useEffect' but not sure where to place it in this example

```
  useOutsideClick(mainRef, () => {
    if (searchInputRef.current) {
      addHistoryEntry(searchInputRef.current.value);
    }
  });
```

This is the code that's responsible for handling outside click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an event with `useEffect` but only doing it when the component mounts. By passing `[]` in as the second argument, you end up creating the `click` event that ends up with a stale object reference after the first render.

Change:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick);
    };
  }, []);
```

to:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick);
    };
  });
```

All I'm doing is removing the second argument. This will remove the old event and create a new event with the proper reference every time the component renders.

I cleaned up some other things, like not using a reference to get input values. https://repl.it/repls/NewEnragedScope

Comment: Wow, I would never have guessed that myself. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! I just edited to add a repl link for some other things I cleaned up. I don't think you generally want to control an input component's value with a reference. Have a look and glad I could help!